# What's the best practice for iterating over an array of AnyObject in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have an array of `AnyObject` that I receive, but I'm positive they're `String`s, for instance.

I tried

```
for string in AnyObjectArray { ... }
```

and

```
for string as String in AnyObjectArray { ... }
```

And both give me errors. How would I best do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're 100% sure they're Strings:

```
for string in AnyObjectArray as [String] { ... }
```

(Less safe, more performant)

If you're not:

```
for obj in AnyObjectArray {
    if let string = obj as? String {
        ...
    }
}
```

(Less performant, safer)